# Ошибка при установке пакета lr-utils. WIndows 10, ошибка сборки py-bcrypt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Не получается поставить пакет lrutils. Ставлю в cmd на Win10 через pip, вылетает ошибка:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: py-bcrypt
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for py-bcrypt ... error
  Failed building wheel for py-bcrypt
  Running setup.py clean for py-bcrypt
Failed to build py-bcrypt
Installing collected packages: py-bcrypt, lrutils
  Running setup.py install for py-bcrypt ... error
```

Пыталась ставить py-bcrypt, ошибка:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: py-bcrypt
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for py-bcrypt ... error
  Failed building wheel for py-bcrypt
  Running setup.py clean for py-bcrypt
Failed to build py-bcrypt
Installing collected packages: py-bcrypt
  Running setup.py install for py-bcrypt ... error
```

В чем проблема? Как исправить? Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Мне кажется в вопросе не весь стек ошибки приведен. Посмотрите, там должно быть что-то еще. А так, я предполагаю что вы столкнулись с багом pip. Смогу точнее сказать если будет полный стек ошибки

Comment: @gil9red Добрый день. В случае с irutils, дальше идут ошибки исключения. Последняя строка: PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'C:\\Users\\fina\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ix95zfa6\\py-bcrypt'

Comment: Если пишет PermissionError значит нужно как администратор запустить команду. Вы через что pip запускали: консоль или IDE?

Comment: @gil9red через консоль от имени администратора

Comment: Файл занят другим процессом... возможно какой-то предыдущий процесс установки не завершен. Убейте такой процесс, или перезагрузитесь и снова попробуйте установить `py-bcrypt`. Кст, а у вас какой питон используется? питон3? Посмотрел в репозитории https://bitbucket.org/alexandrul/py-bcrypt/overview и там написано что модуль работает на питон2. Поискал и нашел аналог, посмотрите: https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt

Comment: @gil9red спасибо. Я перезагружала несколько раз. `bcrypt` установлен, он установился без проблем) но все равно не помогло.

Comment: @gil9red пыталась и вручную, так тоже не получилось.

Comment: Насчет lrutils, вы этот ставите https://github.com/LandRegistry/lr-utils ?

Comment: @gil9red да, он самый.

Comment: Попробовал `pip install lrutils==0.1.1` и у меня все установилось

Comment: @gil9red поставила через сам джупитер. Работает. Спасибо за ответы:)

Comment: О, а расскажите подробнее как поставили

Comment: @gil9red поставила тем же пипом только в джупитер ноутбуке через !pip install lrutils

Comment: Спасибо, неожиданный комментарий. Можете это решение в ответ добавить, чтобы вопрос не висел?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не смогла решить проблему через консоль, но поставила пакет в самом джупитере через `!pip install lrutils`. Работает.